# Meteor select value doesn't update after save to collection

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, select, meteor

I have a bootstrap select dom element that doesnt update after I save some record to the collection.

Please help!

Here is the code:
http://pastebin.com/6FSP3hXq
http://pastebin.com/PUAWp7LY

Comment: You can provide a link to a fiddle, but generally you should include all code in your posts.

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Answer (score 0):

Your helper function `selected` is not reactive.  This means one of the paramets would have to changed reactively for there to be a change.  The only parameter that's a variable is `circuit` and I don't see it set anywhere (unless I'm missing something), so it's probably also always null.  Define `circuit` and define it with a reactive function.

Official reactivity documentation is here: http://docs.meteor.com/#reactivity

Comment: The helper function selected works great! If I just call it from the template in a <p>active {{selected circuit "active"}}</p> it shows the correct value... the select element does not.

Answer (score 0):

Ok! Figured it out! Set "_id" in session variable, then feed it to a findOne return on the helper. :)

Heres the changes:

```
Template.sitesTable.events = {
    "click .site": function(e,t) {
        e.preventDefault();
        Session.set("oid", this._id);
        $("#myModal").modal("show");
        console.log(this);
    }
};

Template.editItem.helpers({
    site: function () {
        return sites.findOne({_id: Session.get("oid")});
    }
});
```